# How do I implement a decoder that calls itself due to one of its fields having the same type?

Tags: elm

How do I implement a decoder that calls itself due to one of its fields having the same type?

```
providerDecoder : Decoder JsonProvider
providerDecoder =
    Decode.map6 JsonProvider
        (field "Profile" profileDecoder)
        (field "Topics" <| Decode.list topicDecoder)
        (field "Links" <| linksDecoder)
        (field "RecentLinks" <| Decode.list linkDecoder)
        (field "Subscriptions" <| Decode.list providerDecoder)
        (field "Followers" <| Decode.list providerDecoder)
```

The following lines are causing issues:

```
(field "Subscriptions" <| Decode.list providerDecoder)
(field "Followers" <| Decode.list providerDecoder)
```

> `providerDecoder` is defined directly in terms of itself, causing an
>   infinite

In conclusion, I am not sure how to resolve this error while still preserving the JsonProvider type.

**Appendix:**

```
type JsonProvider
    = JsonProvider
        { profile : JsonProfile
        , topics : List JsonTopic
        , links : JsonLinks
        , recentLinks : List JsonLink
        , subscriptions : List JsonProvider
        , followers : List JsonProvider
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write recursive JSON decoders, you usually have to rely on [`Json.Decode.lazy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#lazy). You can write those two lines as this:

```elm
(field "Subscriptions" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> providerDecoder)))
(field "Followers" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> providerDecoder)))
```

Once you change that you'll see another error message pop up about the types not matching up, and that's because you're using a single constructor union type that has a record as an argument (which is necessary when writing recursive record types). In this case I usually separate out the constructor and record type like this:

```elm
type JsonProvider
    = JsonProvider JsonProviderFields

type alias JsonProviderFields =
    { profile : JsonProfile
    , topics : List JsonTopic
    , links : JsonLinks
    , recentLinks : List JsonLink
    , subscriptions : List JsonProvider
    , followers : List JsonProvider
    }
```

Now you can rewrite the provider decoder to first decode the `JsonProviderFields` record, then map it to a `JsonProvider`:

```elm
providerDecoder : Decoder JsonProvider
providerDecoder =
    Decode.map6 JsonProviderFields
        (field "Profile" profileDecoder)
        (field "Topics" <| Decode.list topicDecoder)
        (field "Links" <| linksDecoder)
        (field "RecentLinks" <| Decode.list linkDecoder)
        (field "Subscriptions" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> providerDecoder)))
        (field "Followers" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> providerDecoder)))
        |> Decode.map JsonProvider
```