# Decoding a nested list (list of lists with arbitrary depth) recursively

Tags: json, nested-lists, elm

Consider this recursive type definition:

```
type NestedList a
    = Elem a
    | SubList (List (NestedList a))
```

How can I write a decoder in order to decode a JSON list (e.g `[1, [[2, [3, 4]], 5], 6, [7, 8, 9]]`) into the `NestedList` type:

```
SubList
    [ Elem 1
    , SubList [ SubList [ Elem 2, SubList [ Elem 3, Elem 4 ] ], Elem 5 ]
    , Elem 6
    , SubList [ Elem 7, Elem 8, Elem 9 ]
    ]
```

Comment: The code you've posted does not produce that error. It does produce a different error on the type definition, but fixing that, there's no other compiler error. Please make sure to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @glennsl, indeed compiling worked in the end, I had to restart the laptop. My compiler had a temporary bug, perhaps it cached something internally between builds. I will edit the question now, since it makes no sense as it is.

Comment: Then now it's essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230690/how-do-i-implement-a-decoder-that-calls-itself-due-to-one-of-its-fields-having-t/46237498#46237498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done recursively, using `Json.Decode.oneOf` and `Json.Decode.lazy`.
The decoder for a nested list of integers looks like this:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)

nestedListDecoder : Decoder (NestedList Int)
nestedListDecoder =
    Decode.oneOf
        [ Decode.int |> Decode.map Elem
        , Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> nestedListDecoder)) |> Decode.map SubList
        ]
```